# Haskell function on list of tuples

Tags: haskell

Task (home assignment) : Given a list of integers, return a list of tuples where each tuple in the list has the form (int_val, val_freq). No built-in functions are allowed. Allowed operators: :, ++.

Attempt 1:

```
simplify :: [ Int ] -> [( Int , Int )]
simplify [] = []
simplify ((x:xs) ++ [(a, b)]) = 
  if x == a then (simplify xs ++ [(x, b + 1)])
  else  (simplify xs ++ [(x, 0)])
```

Attempt 2:

```
naive_enumerate :: [ Int ] -> [( Int , Int )]
naive_enumerate [] = []
naive_enumerate x:xs = 
  if x == y then [(y, 1)] ++ naive_enumerate xs

enumerate_tuple_list :: [( Int , Int )] -> [( Int , Int )]
enumerate_tuple_list [] = []
enumerate_tuple_list ((a, b):(c, d):rest) = 
  if (a == c) then (a, b+d):(enumerate_tuple_list rest)
  else (a, b+d):(enumerate_tuple_list rest)


simplify :: [ Int ] -> [( Int , Int )]
simplify some_list = enumerate_tuple_list (naive_enumerate some_list)
```

Expected: For e.g. input of [1, 2, 2, 3] an output of [(1,1), (2, 2), (3,1)]. 
Actual result: in attempt 1, I got an error at

> simplify ((x:xs) ++ [(a, b)]) =

In attempt 2, my parse error occurs at

> enumerate_tuple_list :: [( Int , Int )] -> [( Int , Int )]

Questions:

1. What is the correct syntax to iterate over tuples in a list?
2. Can you explain why I get both parser errors?
3. Why does Haskell forbid code like the following:

   naive_enumerate x:xs = [(x, 1)] ++ naive_enumerate xs

**Update: Attempt 3:** Thanks to the suggestions so far, I now have

```
simplify :: [ Int ] -> [( Int , Int )]
simplify [] = []
simplify (x:xs) = let recursive_result = simplify xs
                  update n ((a, b):pairs) = 
                      if n == a then ((a, b + 1):pairs)
                      else ((n, 1):pairs)
                  in update x recursive_result
```

Now the code compiles, but I get the following error:

> Exception: ... Non-exhaustive patterns in function update

Hence the additional questions:

4. Which case(s) am I missing?
5. Is it possible to catch the error at compile time (debug/verbose options don't do the trick)?

Comment: A full answer will take longer than I have at the moment (but I'm sure someone else will provide one soon). But your parse error in Attempt 2 is because you have an `if ... then` statement with no `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks to all respondents. I will answer all my questions here and at the end of the answer provide a (spoiler) sample solution.

> 1. What is the correct syntax to iterate over tuples in a list?

Lists should not be iterated over. To write a function on such a data structure,

> function_name ((element1, element2, ..., elementN):some_list) = *result*

My error was that I disregarded the binding priority of the list creation constructor : and function application.

> 2. Can you explain why I get both parser errors?

Answered already.

> 3. Why does Haskell forbid code like the following:

Explained by chepner.

> 4. Which case(s) am I missing?

The case that there are 1-element-lists.

> 5. Is it possible to catch the error at compile time?

Possible by using [HTF](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTF).

SPOILER ALERT
And here comes my **Attempt 5**:

```
simplify :: [ Int ] -> [( Int , Int )]
simplify [] = []
simplify (x:xs) = let recursive_result = simplify xs
                  update n [] = [(n, 1)]
                  update n ((a, b):pairs) = 
                      if n == a then ((a, b + 1):pairs)
                      else (a, b):(update n pairs)
              in update x recursive_result
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently trying to iterate over your return value as if it were an argument. You need to make the recursive call first, *then* update that result

```
simplify [] = []
simplify (x:xs) = let recursive_result = simplify xs
                      update n pairs = ...
                  in update x recursive_result
```

where `...` is where you try to find and replace the pair which already contains `x`, or add a new pair.

Hint: the builtin `lookup` function would help, if you can convince your teacher to let you use it.